# sessionStorage doesn't clear after clear() (localhost)

Tags: javascript, session-storage

**Situation**

I'm testing a website with db via localhost. I got 2 pages (for examples sake: `index.aspx` and `other.aspx`).

On `index.aspx`, I use `sessionStorage` to see if some data is cached, if not I fetch the date from the db.

If the user goes to `other.aspx`, the sessionStorage is always cleared using `window.sessionStorage.clear();`

If I use the dev tools (google chrome), I can see that the sessionStorage is empty after the `clear()`, but if I reload the page, or go to `index.aspx`, all the data is back again.

**Code:**

index.aspx:

```
if (typeof (Storage) == "undefined")
     return false;

var data = window.sessionStorage.getItem("importantInformation");
if (data != undefined && data != null)
    console.log("important information is here");
```

other.aspx:

```
window.sessionStorage.clear();
```

**Desired result:**

if I do a `clear()`, that the sessionStorage actually is empty.. As it should be.

Comment: Is there any difference at all between the host part of the URL? For instance, SO's host section is "http:///stackoverflow.com/". If I navigated to "http:// www .stackoverflow.com/", then it would be using a different sessionStorage. (spaces to break comment links)

Comment: @Katana314 no, both are `http://localhost:55420/*page-here*`, but even then: if I just reload `other.aspx` the data is back as well.

Comment: are you setting the value of importantInformation in index.aspx?

Comment: @MauricePerry No, I set it on a third page: `addValue.aspx` where is use `window.sessionStorage.setItem("importantInformation","answerToLife")`

Comment: Wouldn't you use || instead of &&